# we are off to a fine start

Tags: phrase-meaning

**At the cleaning service**

Manager: Hello. Can I help you?

Man: Are you a cleaning lady?

Manager: Certainly not.

Man: But this is a cleaning service, isn't it?

Manager: Yes.

Man: So, why aren't you a cleaning lady?

Manager: Well, I used to be a cleaning lady, but I'm not anymore. Now, I'm the manager.

Man: But you do employ cleaning ladies, don't you?

Manager: Yes, but only of the highest quality. This is quality Cleaning Services, after all. Ha, ha, ha.

Man: Ha, ha, ha. What does quality mean?

Manager: Doesn't know what quality means... Now **we are off to a fine start**. Quality, excellence, the best.We are the best cleaning service.

Man: The best cleaning service. That's good because I want...

Manager: And we only employ the best cleaners.

---

What does "**we are off to a fine start**" mean?

Comment: **This business is beginning well.** It's sarcastic. I'm not sure why the manager says it, though. I suppose she means that, if the man is looking to hire a cleaning lady, he is not starting very well if he doesn't even know what a high-quality service is.

Answer (score 1):

This is *sarcasm*. The manager's words would indicate that they are beginning well, but what is meant is the opposite. The statement implies that if this is how things start, then surely even worse things are ahead.

This is also most likely a British, Aussie, or NZ TV show, as this saying is often if not exclusively used in those places.

See: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sarcasm

Comment: Probably the off-the-wall Canadian show from the '80s that the OP gets on youtube

Comment: Yes, very true. It could be Canadian as well.